# Migrating From Google Custom Search API v1 To v2?

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

Recently a client site began posting the following warning in the console:

> This page is calling an old version of the Custom Search API, which is deprecated and will stop working soon. In order to avoid an outage for the search results, the call for search results must be updated to the current version of the Custom Search API https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element.

While searching around trying to figure out how to handle this I've come across [this forum post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/customsearch/0-X_x2q4EWk) and subsequently [this post](https://customsearch.googleblog.com/2017/02/refocusing-and-looking-forward-on.html) of the announcement itself, but no clear API migration document (i.e. "if you are doing this you should replace this function with this other function.")

Has anyone done this who might know where to find a list of the potential gotchas while upgrading and/or any specific notes on what to replace or am I going to be stuck with reading through the API between the two call-by-call and making a comparison of the two?

Comment: I think the blog post tells you what to do doesn't it?  https://customsearch.googleblog.com/2017/02/refocusing-and-looking-forward-on.html

Comment: @DaImTo No direct conversion path is outlined.  i.e. "if you are making this call, this is the replacement call" for each entry in the API.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a few months late, but I just tackled this issue on my website.  It was a lot of trial and error, but I now have Google Custom Search, using API v2, working on my site.  Our Google Custom Search Elements are configured to do a 'two-page' display, where the Search Box element is separate from the Search Results element.

The previous administrator built the search features of my site using CSE APIv1 and Google's Java API.  You know your site is using Google's Java API with Custom Search if the code for your search box and/or your search results contains the following near the top:

```
<script src="//www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script> //Call to Google's Java API
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
google.load('search', '1');
. . . some other Java functions . . . 
// ]]></script>

<form>
<input to javascript function X()>
<input text from user>
<input submit button>
</form>
```

As seen above, the previous administrator also had a very simple HTML form element, used to get the data from the user.  This data is then fed to the javascript functions designed to interface with GCSE search box elements.

Keep the javascript / HTML code your site is using for the Search Box element(s); lose the javascript / HTML for Search Results element(s).  You really only need to transition the Search Results element to GCSE API v2, if your site is using Google's Java API.  BTW, we're doing all this on our site within Drupal 7 blocks.

The only change I needed to do to the Search Box element was to REMOVE line 3 in the above code excerpt -- 'google.load('search', '1');.

I removed all of the code previously built for the Search Results element / page (our resultsUrl), and replaced it with:

```
<script src="sites/all/themes/eu/js/gsearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

The locally stored 'gsearch.js' file contains all the details about our orginazation's CSE console, including our XXX:YYY ID.

A great advantage of using Google's Java API to port data to GCS, instead using of the GCSE API (any version) in the Search Box elements, is that it allows the Search Box to work even on the Search Results page.  Using *only* the GCSE API, does not let one add a searchbox-only and a searchresults-only element to the same page (Drupal node).